# SSMS Tabular Model: create multiple partition via one single xmla script

Tags: ssms, ssas, partitioning, ssas-tabular

I need to create a considerable number of partitions using XMLA scripts run through SSMS.
Is there a way to combine the creation of multiple partitions into one single script.

In below example, I need to execute the first script. When it finishes, I can open the other script and execute it as well. Very time consuming.

How can I restructure the code to run it in only one execution?

### Script 1:

```
  "createOrReplace": {
    "object": {
      "database": "MYDB",
      "table": "MYTABLE1",      "partition": "Partition"
    },
    "partition": {
      "name": "Process_OLD",      "dataView": "full",
      "source": {
        "type": "m",
        "expression": [
          "let",
          "    Source = #\"mySQL/MY_SCHEMA\",",          "    MY_SCHEMA= Source{[Schema=\"MY_SCHEMA\"]}[Data],",
          "    AllData = MY_SCHEMA{[Name=\"MYTABLE1\"]}[Data],",          "\t#\"Filtered Rows\" = Table.SelectRows(AllData, each  [DATE]  < 20170101)",
          "in",
          "    #\"Filtered Rows\""
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Script 2:

```
  "createOrReplace": {
    "object": {
      "database": "MYDB",
      "table": "MYTABLE2",      "partition": "Partition"
    },
    "partition": {
      "name": "Process_NEW",      "dataView": "full",
      "source": {
        "type": "m",
        "expression": [
          "let",
          "    Source = #\"mySQL/MY_SCHEMA\",",          "    MY_SCHEMA= Source{[Schema=\"MY_SCHEMA\"]}[Data],",
          "    AllData = MY_SCHEMA{[Name=\"MYTABLE1\"]}[Data],",          "\t#\"Filtered Rows\" = Table.SelectRows(AllData, each  [DATE]  >= 20170101)",
          "in",
          "    #\"Filtered Rows\""
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `sequence` command around it:

```
{
  "sequence": {
    "operations": [
      {
        "createOrReplace": {
          "object": {
            "database": "MYDB",
            "table": "MYTABLE1",
            "partition": "Partition"
          },
          "partition": {
            "name": "Process_OLD",
            "dataView": "full",
            "source": {
              "type": "m",
              "expression": [
                "let",
                "    Source = #\"mySQL/MY_SCHEMA\",",
                "    MY_SCHEMA= Source{[Schema=\"MY_SCHEMA\"]}[Data],",
                "    AllData = MY_SCHEMA{[Name=\"MYTABLE1\"]}[Data],",
                "\t#\"Filtered Rows\" = Table.SelectRows(AllData, each  [DATE]  < 20170101)",
                "in",
                "    #\"Filtered Rows\""
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "createOrReplace": {
          "object": {
            "database": "MYDB",
            "table": "MYTABLE2",
            "partition": "Partition"
          },
          "partition": {
            "name": "Process_NEW",
            "dataView": "full",
            "source": {
              "type": "m",
              "expression": [
                "let",
                "    Source = #\"mySQL/MY_SCHEMA\",",
                "    MY_SCHEMA= Source{[Schema=\"MY_SCHEMA\"]}[Data],",
                "    AllData = MY_SCHEMA{[Name=\"MYTABLE1\"]}[Data],",
                "\t#\"Filtered Rows\" = Table.SelectRows(AllData, each  [DATE]  >= 20170101)",
                "in",
                "    #\"Filtered Rows\""
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: how did you know the use of `sequence` and `operations`?

Comment: TMSL docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tmsl/tmsl-reference-commands